# is it possible to have a separate backend for next js application?

Tags: react-native, mobile, next.js, backend

I am working on an app right now I just want to know is it possible to create a **separate backend** for the next js application because I want to connect react native app and web application with the same backend. Is it possible? and can I use **getinitialprops** and server-side props while having separate backend???

Comment: Yes, you can pull data from wherever you need it.  You can call your custom API (separate backend) client-side or server-side. Using `getInitalProps` isn't recommended - use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` - see [Next.js data-fetching docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
API Routes of Next Js can be use as backend, but it is optional.

getinitialprops, getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, are fetching methods of Next Js to handle the data and APIs in a headless way, so you can use any backend that expose an API.

Here are few ides for the arquitecture:

- Next JS for webapp and Backend, React Native fetching Next Js API Routes
- Next JS and react native in one project https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/ and any backend that you want to use
- The last is project for each (Next, React Native, Backend)

Comment: Have you used next/expo in production - if so, how did it work?

Comment: Yes, i did. it has a lot of develop experience and is really stable. In my case i use it as first option because if expo doesnt for your use case you can eject and continue in react native "vanilla". In production works in my case as i expected. The only thing I see as contracting the compilation time of the packages if you use the expo service to export APPs. Here is a use case of expo and next js https://youtu.be/0lnbdRweJtA

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys it means a lot as a junior developer @Pablopvsky

Answer (score -1):

Backend is all about having the data. Nextjs has many fetching methods for both server side rendering and static generation. To fetch the data from backend, you can go with getStaticProps, getServerSideProps or getInitialProps. You can also fetch data locally by providing a simple json file within the application.